# .htaccess wont work after installing apache

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, centos

I just installed on my new centos server apache and im trying to use .htaccess file,
the server don't refers  to the .htaccess file,
i have tried to use the main htaccess and another one just for checking

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^test\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

i have changed my httpd.conf like allow override all like that :

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

and i have restarted httpd, what else could be my problem? 
thanks :)

Comment: What's your DocumentRoot for your vhosts?

Comment: @user2326568: Make sure above rule is placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: my document root is DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
and the htaccess placed in /var/www/html/.htaccess

Comment: Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Or try add AccessFileName .htaccess
 in  httpd.conf